# Django CharField with choices, auto add possible choices to database on syncdb or migrate?

Tags: python, django

I know there is a way to automatically add values to database on syncdb, which is Fixtures. But I was thinking maybe there's a way to detect the choices and automatically create those number of choices on database on syncdb or migrate.

The reason why I want this:

```
SERVICE_TYPES = (
    ("SALE", _("Sale")),
    ("RENT", _("Rent"))
)

class ServiceType(models.Model):

    type_of_service = models.CharField(_("Type of service"), choices=SERVICE_TYPES, default=SERVICE_TYPES[0][0], max_length=20)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Service Type"
        verbose_name_plural = "Services Types"

    def __str__(self):
        pass


class Service(models.Model):
    service_type = models.ForeignKey(ServiceType)
    product_family = models.ManyToManyField(ProductFamily)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Service"
        verbose_name_plural = "Services"

    def __str__(self):
        pass
```

I would like that, on syncdb, the ServiceType automatically generates the two possible choices on database, so then I can add services with the Sale and Rent choices available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a data migration that loops through `SERVICE_TYPES` and makes sure that the table for `ServiceType` reflects that. You can see how you can do that here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/#data-migrations

Are you sure you don't want to make `type_of_service` an attribute on `Service` directly? It makes the most sense if you aren't going to add extra attributes to `ServiceType`. If you are going to add extra attributes for different types of services, I'd rather create a different subclass for each type of service.

Comment: Thanks, in the end I will use it as you said and make type_of_service as an attribute on Service. But the data-migrations its what I really needed to know.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add this to the model:

```
SERVICE_TYPES = (
    ('sale', 'Sale'),
    ('rent', 'Rent') 
)
service_type=models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False, choices=SERVICE_TYPES)
```